# R View() function does not show data frame

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using R (Version 3.1.2) with RStudio (Version 0.98.1091) on a Linux Ubuntu machine. I have a csv file loaded in variable:

```
rr  <- read.csv("/home/user/seconds.csv")
```

When I call `View(rr)` I expect to open a new tab and display the CSV data in the rr variable. However, it opens a new tab called rr and it displays the following message.

```
/content?title=rr&file=94af460bd6644d3aaac734d585046c4f.htm not found
```

Comment: I'm not sure how we are expected to debug this with the information at hand. It might be better to bring this to the RStudio support forums.

Comment: To expand Rolands comment, please check if `utils::View(rr)` works

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the remark. I edited my question, including what I expect to happen normally in RStudio, if you can suggest any more clarifications I would make them. I will try utils::View(rr) when it happens next and I will let you know.

Comment: We know what is supposed to happen.

Comment: In the environment window (top right) within Rstudio, do you see `rr` listed when you `read.csv` ?

Comment: From a quick google search, it looks like a permissions issue: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200658763-can-t-view-datasets Hopefully someone more fluent in Linux permissions than me can shed more light.

Comment: @LukeSingham Yes, I do.

Comment: And have you checked on the command line whether `rr` actually is correct either by `head(rr)` or by `str(rr)`. This is just to make sure that your file is actually correct.

Comment: @PaulLemmens yes i have

Comment: I have the same issue for a data.frame I have created programmatically, head() produces the right result and View() works for other data.frames. Running Rstudio as admin solved the problem. I am using Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The View function is from package 'utils' which is not supported by the version of R you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I am on a x86_64-w64-mingw32 system with R version 3.4.1, but I want to share a simple solution to get View working again in my case.

Following the step 4 of advice from Tian on Rstudio support (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115007743908-The-Rstudio-view-not-work-just-blank-), I entered:

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to packages in R and install veiwpoly package then view function will start working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).